# What does it mean to demean oneself?

Tags: political-philosophy, paradox

The State of Texas Bar Association has each new member take the [following oath](http://www.texasbar.com/Content/NavigationMenu/ForLawyers/MembershipInfoandServices/NewLawyerFormsFees/OathofOfficeForm.pdf):

> I,___ , do affirm that I will support the Constitution of the United States, and of this State; that I will honestly demean myself in the practice of the law, and will discharge my duties to my clients to the best of my ability.

The order of obligations is not unnoticed.  This oath appears to mandate one to degrade themselves and to expel their duties onto their clients?

*This is an important question that impacts the lives of many people and I feel like a philosophical inquiry in to its meaning is valuable.*

Comment: To *discharge* ones duties does not mean 'expel their duties onto their clients'; but that one actually *carries out* ones duties; it's an archaic sense of discharge, not really used now; similarly, I expect *demean* does not *abase* - but quite what it means I do not know.

Comment: I would bet by 'honestly demean' they mean 'have an honest demeanor' -- to be who one appears to be and not present a false and misleading image to the system.  (How that is consistent with adversarial law and 'honestly' representing people who know they are guilty, but are scared to admit it, which is the norm in U.S. law, totally escapes me.)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a question about philosophy. This is about English / law.

Comment: @Keelan: there is such a thing as a *philosophy of law*; see, for example [Unger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Mangabeira_Unger) and [nausbaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Nussbaum); having said this, the question doesn't really touch upon law; but simply its language in a specific text.

Comment: @jobermark: is there such a thing as *non-adversial* law?

Comment: I agree with @MoziburUllah that "there is such a thing as a philosophy of law," but this question can be solved by looking at a dictionary: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/demean?s=t, see the second definition

Comment: @Keelan Is it possible for you to remove your downgrading of my question?  This site is not restricted to explaining philosophical concepts or the historical accounting of identified as philosophers.

Comment: @jobermark Good idea.  I think it is important to distinguish between truth and man-made law (Statutes).  Legislatures articulate statutes that must be met, to the letter of the law, by prosecutors/plaintiffs.  Of course, poor articulation (lack of Philosophical training) results in easily sidestepped laws.

Comment: No: this question is off topic here (see the [help center](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and Mozibur's and James' comments. **If** there's a philosophical question here, it's not clear. As far as I can see you want us to be your dictionary.

Comment: @staps: I think its useful to encourage questions from a wider field of human experience; it probably means we will get questions that are 'low' quality first; but one can hope that will improve.

Comment: @Keelan Does this question not fall under applied philosophy?  BTW: I use Google's "`define:demean`" and "`define:discharge`".  So looking in a dictionary is quite effortless (and was done).

Comment: When I read your question, and the answer you deemed 'good' (which is merely stating some definition and a corollary), this is a question about a definition, which makes it off topic here. So unless there's *another* question here besides "What does it mean to demean oneself?" this question is off topic here. *If* there's another question, it's not clear from your question, so please [edit] it to clarify in that case.

Comment: @MoziburUllah At least officially, countries like France have a judgment-centered 'inquisitorial' theory of law, rather than a theory centered on a directly adversarial stance.  Judges are specialists with advanced degrees, not appointed by political actors from amongst the legal profession, or elected (in the U.S. this often just means vetted by a party, as most elected judges run unopposed).  Attorneys represent clients, but serve the court, instead of serving clients and being partial officers of the court.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  The point is that in Common Law, everyone is meant to say whatever best serves their allegiances, in Civil Law, everyone is meant to say what they actually believe -- so lying is mandatory in the former and optional in the latter.

Comment: @Keelan Sticking with the posed question.  The context is clearly in The State of Texas Bar Association Oath.  This is applied philosophy.  Do you seriously not understand the question "What does it mean to demean oneself"?  How could I improve on it?  I am looking for the meaning in the context provided.  Please help me rephrase to your satisfaction.

Comment: No, I can't help you with this. If really all you want with this question is the meaning of a word in a not even philosophical context, it's simply off topic here. Sorry.

Comment: @Ron What is the idea you consider good?  I am confused.  But I do agree with @-Keelan this belongs in English Language and Usage.  The question is about words, not concepts.  And the answer is about the history of the words 'demeanor' and '(dis)charge', and how they have older interpretations in law than in everyday practice,

Comment: @Keelan I am seriously unable to understand the foundation of Texas jurisprudence (the oath of its operators).  Is that not philosophy of law, insofar as I am seeking wisdom regarding the law?

Comment: It's a juridical question, not a philosophical one. You may be interested in [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law?referrer=vgxxNA48hoYIoi5i8nXuKg2).

Comment: @jobermark I believe we should comment on the proposed answer _under_ the proposed answer, no?  But, I used good as a means to encourage more participation.  Noone wan't to be told that their contribution is _no good_.  BTW notice I did not accept the answer and did not upvote it either.

Comment: @Keelan  What is a philosophical question anyways, if not a question seeking meaning?  What do you mean, _philosophical question_?  Surely you can explain what one is or looks like?  I have read the help center.

Comment: @Ron.  The proposed 'answer' is in a comment, because I do not consider this a worthwhile question for this board, and don't want to honor it with an answer.

Comment: There are two threads here, one belongs on EL&U the other belongs in 'meta'.  (And half of my comments are just off-topic, sorry.)  Let's take our concerns wherever they belong.

Comment: @jobermark Agreed.  I sincerely bring questions for philosophical inquiry, my questions are frequently poo-poo'd by many, so it's probably me, not you. :-)

Comment: @Ron (While we are on a language question and off topic anyway, I hope your questions are pooh-pooh'ed and not poo-poo'ed.  Removing feces from our boards would be disgusting.)

Comment: @Jobermark is right. If you want to discuss this further, consider asking a question on [meta] (but not without first reading the [help], in case you didn't do that yet!).

Answer (score 1):

Demean basically means "humbling" yourself or "lowering yourself in rank".

In this context you are stating that you place yourself **below** the law so the rank of the law is greater than your rank if you have any,
basically stating that you accept the law and will follow it. 
that's at least how I understood it.

Comment: Good answer; however applying this understanding requires that the attorney might also place herself equal with the law or above the law.  It seems all citizens would aim to place themselves equal to the law(s), neither above or below.  Does that make sense?